# Question about a proof of a calculus inequality

Tags: calculus

I've been reading a book in which I encountered the following inequality:

$|f(t)|\leq \frac{1}{2} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty}|f'(s)|ds$
for any smooth function $f$, with a compact support on the real line.

I can obtain the inequality without the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ by the following argument:

Since $f$ is compactly supported, there exists $t\geq a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\leq a$. Then from the fundemental theorem of calculus we obtain:

$\int_{\infty}^{\infty}|f'(s)|ds \geq \int_{a}^{t}|f'(s)|ds \geq |\int_{a}^{t}f'(s)ds|=|f(t)-f(a)|=|f(t)|$

But I am at a loss as to how the inequality with the factor is obtained. The book I found this in makes no mention or gives refrence as to how this inequality is achieved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say that the support of $f$ is contained in $[a,b]$.
For every $t\in (a,b)$ you have that:
$$
f(t) = \int_a^t f'(x)\, dx,
\qquad
f(t) = \int_b^t f'(x)\, dx
$$
hence
$$
|f(t)| \leq \int_a^t |f'(x)|\, dx,
\qquad
|f(t)| \leq \int_t^b |f'(x)|\, dx.
$$
Summing the two inequalities:
$$
2 |f(t)| \leq \int_a^b |f'| = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f'|.
$$